# Java/Spring: Provide a common implementation java function (Supplier or Function...)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently, I've this class:

```
@Component
public class AuditFactory {

    private Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier;

    public AuditFactory(Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier) {
        this.auditIdSupplier = auditIdSupplier;
    }
}
```

I've coded two projects are using this `AuditFactory`.

Currently I'm providing them using this `@Bean`:

In project `front-office`:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier(FrontOfficeProperties frontOfficeProperties) {
    return () -> String.join(
        "-",
        frontOfficeProperties.getCpdId(),
        UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    );
}
```

In project `back-office`:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier(BackOfficeProperties backOfficeProperties) {
    return () -> String.join(
        "-",
        backOfficeProperties.getCpdId(),
        UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    );
}
```

So, I'd like to avoid to create so many `Supplier<String>` implementations as projects I need in order to provide a same way of creating an common way to provide an `id`.

What only is changing is one parameter (`cpdid`).

So, I guess, I could create a class that inherits from `Supplier<String>`, but I don't quite figure out how to get it.

Comment: Is `AuditFactory` coming from a separate module?

Comment: Have a look at @ConfigurationProperties, you can load your id into a bean and autowire it in your AuditFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `AuditFactory` is stored in a separate module, you could simply move `Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier()` to that module and have both `FrontOfficeProperties` and `BackOfficeProperties` implement the same `c` interface.

Then, whenever you will build `front-office` or `back-office`, a proper `OfficeProperties` would be injected.